# How to count number of characters in string for the column values and group rows by count of those as a result using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have .csv file with column name:

```
id    name
1    sample1
2    sample3
3    sample four
4    sample.five
5    sample.six.com
```

I need to print result as below (ordered by number of rows descending):

```
chars(str_len_count)    rows(id_count)
  7                          2
 11                          2
 14                          1
```

I've tried the below, but this is not really what I'm looking for:

```
In [106]:
df['NAME_Count'] = df['name'].str.len()
df

Out[106]:
       name        NAME_Count
0     sample1        7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First new column is not necessary, you can pass `str.len` to `groupby` and use [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) for count:

```
df1 = df.groupby(df['name'].str.len().rename('chars')).size().reset_index(name='id_count')
print (df1)
   chars  id_count
0      7         2
1     11         2
2     14         1
```

If want first create new column solution is a bit changed:

```
df['NAME_Count'] = df['name'].str.len()
df1 = df.groupby('NAME_Count').size().reset_index(name='count')
```